# Ruby on rails "anchor tag" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to "Course", university_course_path(@room.username), 
            class: "item", "data-tab": "course" %>
```

I tried to add "data tab": link_to ,But the link not working.
Can you tell me that sollutions

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091550/whats-the-right-way-to-define-an-anchor-tag-in-rails

Comment: Is that giving any error or rendering as plain text. Can you be bit more specific on "link not working"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<%= link_to "Course", university_course_path(@room.username), 
            class: "item", "data-tab" => "course" %>
```